# Windows 10 command line/script - for or loop filename(1), filename(2)

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am writing a script (batch file) currently to run at Windows Command Line. The task is I have a variable number of files in a folder. The files are named in the format of filename(1), filename(2) ... etc.

I am trying to set a FOR loop or using a IF ... GOTO to move filenames(1 to 9) to one folder, then filenames (10 to 99) to another folder and so on so I can deal with them separately.

So, easy way would be to copy in sequence to join to source files into a single target file. Alternatively a way to construct a filename for a copy and/or move command that looked at files such as test(1), test(2), ... test(9) in order and then stop.

Files are sorted in folder in following order - test(1).txt test(2).txt test(3).txt test(4).txt test(5).txt test(6).txt test(7).txt test(8).txt test(9).txt

There may only be two or three files however, or there maybe 1000 files in the folder to be dealt with.

I have been trying to set something like this up:

```
set count1=9
set count2=99
set count_loop=1

:while_loop1
echo "count_loop = " %count_loop%
move test(%count_loop%) proto\9\
set /a "count_loop = count_loop + 1"
if %count_loop% leq %count1% (
    echo test(%count_loop%) moved
     goto while_loop1)
```

I could do with some advice here.

Cheers, Thomo the Lost

Comment: I think a better option to iterate through all your files is to use a `FOR /L`.

Comment: What problem or error occurs?

Comment: It was a case of not being able to find the file. As it turns out there is really two parts to the problem:

Part 1. The looping and setting the variable correctly. As suggested by @Squashman using:

`code`for /L %%G IN (1 1 9) DO (copy test(%%G).* new_folder\*) 

worked a treat. Thanks for that.

Part 2. There was a failure to recognise the filename. I missed out using the '^' symbol so my code now looks like:

`code`for /L %%G IN (1 1 9) DO (copy test^(%%G^).* new_folder\*)

So, thanks for the help folks, problem is now solved!

Cheers, Thomo the Lost